# Ceramic tiles on concrete walls

Tags: concrete, walls

Can I put ceramic tiles right on my poured basement walls ?  I want to put a shower in and tile the walls floor and cieling. Should I put a false wall and tile over it or can I put ceramic right on the concrete?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely put tiles right on the concrete wall. However, if you're building a shower, it's critically important that you have a waterproof membrane separating the finish materials (tile) from the structure (concrete walls and cement backboard on any framed walls you build). I suggest painting the walls with Redgard, a sort of paintable rubber. You paint the floor, too. Then you tile over that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, concrete is the perfect base for adhering tile to. As long as it is sound and sturdy. Also check for plumb (not as critical). As iLikeDirt answered , steps should be taken to prevent moisture from migrating into the wood framing (Via the concrete walls). Sealing them, as he suggested works well. The concrete wall should have a vapor barrier already installed under it, but a second is good insurance.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what they do in China. A worker used generous amounts of concrete applied directly to the back of the tile and then set in place. This was in the kitchen area. For the bathroom I believe they put a plastic membrane in place first for waterproofing.